# Django Framework- page not found

Tags: python, django, jinja2

Why am i getting a 404 in this?

This is my mysite/urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^$/', include('personal.urls')),
]
```

And this is my mysite/personal/urls.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns =[url(r'^$',views.index, name='index')]
```

The mysite/personal/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'personal/home.html')
```

after that i have created the templates folder like templates/personal/header.html. The file looks like this

```
<body class="body" style="background-color:#f6f6f6">
<div>
   {% block content %}
   {% endblock %}   
</div>
</body>
```

Now about the home.html in the same folder

```
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}
{% block content %}
<p>Hey! Welcome to my website! Well, I wasn't expecting guests. Um, my name is HVS. I am a programmer.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

I HAVE ALSO INSTALLED THE APP IN settings.py file in mysite sub directory but still when i run the

```
">python manage.py runserver"
```

it runs OK bt the page tells me that the url not found 404!!

This is my browser output:

[image: Screenshot]

I am using Windows 8, python 3 & django 1.9

Comment: You didn't provide the most important piece of information: what url are you trying to access?

Comment: First, you forgot the first argument `request` in your view. By the way, we need the URL attempted to know what it is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `$` from your main `urls.py` where you include `personal.urls`:

```
url(r'^/', include('personal.urls')),
```

The `$` specifier will always match the end of the string (ie. your URL) and you will not be able to include any additional paths beyond it.

Comment: actually this `r'^/'` dint work for me but this did: `r'^$' `

Comment: Remove the trailing slash as well, i.e. use `r'^'`. Using `r'^$` works for your index URL, but it will not work for any other URLs that you add to `personal/urls.py`.

Answer (score 2):

According to django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/):

> The include() function allows referencing other URLconfs. Note that
>   the regular expressions for the include() function doesn’t have a $
>   (end-of-string match character) but rather a trailing slash

So you should change it to this:

```
url(r'^/', include('personal.urls'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This url here won't ever match

```
r'^$/'
```

The `$` matches end of string.  That means it's never possible for a `/` to come after it.

You probably want

```
url(r'^personal/', include('personal.urls')),
```

Comment: Nope nothing seems to work, but only this `r'^$'`. Could you please explain why is that so?